# Django all-auth testing error - django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: socialaccount_openidstore

Tags: python, django, django-allauth, django-testing

can anyone help with this Django allauth issue? I'm running Django 1.8 with Python 3 in a virtualenv. I've got allauth installed and working OK in my project but I get an error message when I try and run any tests. Here is the simplest replication of the error I can get:

I create a new project, then download the django-allauth .zip file and copy the allauth directory into my project directory. I add the following apps to INSTALLED_APPS in settings:

```
'django.contrib.sites',
'allauth',
'allauth.account',
'allauth.socialaccount',
'allauth.socialaccount.providers.facebook',
```

then run `python manage.py migrate`. So far so good, but when I run `python manage.py test` I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/AGG/Dropbox/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/AGG/Dropbox/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 318, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: socialaccount_openidstore

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/AGG/Dropbox/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 338, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/AGG/Dropbox/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 330, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Users/AGG/Dropbox/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/test.py", line 30, in run_from_argv
    super(Command, self).run_from_argv(argv)
  File "/Users/AGG/Dropbox/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 390, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/Users/AGG/Dropbox/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/test.py", line 74, in execute
    super(Command, self).execute(*args, **options)
  File "/Users/AGG/Dropbox/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 441, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/Users/AGG/Dropbox/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/test.py", line 90, in handle
    failures = test_runner.run_tests(test_labels)
  File "/Users/AGG/Dropbox/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/test/runner.py", line 210, in run_tests
    old_config = self.setup_databases()
  File "/Users/AGG/Dropbox/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/test/runner.py", line 166, in setup_databases
    **kwargs
  File "/Users/AGG/Dropbox/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/test/runner.py", line 370, in setup_databases
    serialize=connection.settings_dict.get("TEST", {}).get("SERIALIZE", True),
  File "/Users/AGG/Dropbox/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/creation.py", line 376, in create_test_db
    self.connection._test_serialized_contents = self.serialize_db_to_string()
  File "/Users/AGG/Dropbox/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/creation.py", line 413, in serialize_db_to_string
    serializers.serialize("json", get_objects(), indent=None, stream=out)
  File "/Users/AGG/Dropbox/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/serializers/__init__.py", line 129, in serialize
    s.serialize(queryset, **options)
  File "/Users/AGG/Dropbox/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/serializers/base.py", line 52, in serialize
    for obj in queryset:
  File "/Users/AGG/Dropbox/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/creation.py", line 409, in get_objects
    for obj in queryset.iterator():
  File "/Users/AGG/Dropbox/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 238, in iterator
    results = compiler.execute_sql()
  File "/Users/AGG/Dropbox/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 829, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/AGG/Dropbox/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/AGG/Dropbox/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 97, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/Users/AGG/Dropbox/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/utils/six.py", line 658, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/Users/AGG/Dropbox/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/AGG/Dropbox/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 318, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: socialaccount_openidstore
```

I've tried deleting the database or project and starting again. I can't find this issue elsewhere on StackOverflow. Extra information: the error goes away if I delete the tests files in allauth or comment out `'allauth.socialaccount'` in INSTALLED_APPS. I'm very confused about the "openidstore" table - is it something to do with the migrations in allauth/socialaccount/providers/openid?

Comment: Means the table is not getting created for some model. If the problem goes away when you remove the app from installed list, chances are the model is in that app. The latest version of allauth doesn't seem to have any model for OpenIDStore. So some code somewhere is probably referring to some code that was dropped in development process.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Add 'allauth.socialaccount.providers.openid' to INSTALLED_APPS
2. manage.py makemigrations
3. manage.py migrate

That solved it for me.

Answer (score 2):

I've succeeded with these lines to INSTALLED_APPS.

```
'allauth',
'allauth.account',
'allauth.socialaccount',
'allauth.socialaccount.providers.openid',
```